# Pattern match in perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
my $line = "Name:Amanda_Marry_Rose,Region:US,host:USE,cardType:DebitCard,product:Satin,Name:Raghav.S.Thomas,Region:UAE,";
my $name = "";

@name = ( $line =~ m/Name:([\w\s\_\,/g );
foreach (@name) {
   print $name."\n";
}
```

I want to capture the word between `Name:` and `,Region` whereever it occurs in the whole line. The main loophole is that the name can be of any format

```
Amanda_Marry_Rose
Amanda.Marry.Rose
Amanda Marry Rose
Amanda/Marry/Rose
```

I need a help in capturing such a pattern every time it occurs in the line. So for the line I provided, the output should be

```
Amanda_Marry_Rose
Raghav.S.Thomas
```

Does anyone has any idea how to do this? I tried keeping the below line, but it's giving me the wrong output as.

```
@name=($line=~m/Name:([\w\s\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\=\>\?\@\[\\\]\^\_\`\{\|\}\~\´]+)\,/g);
```

Output

```
Amanda_Marry_Rose,Region:US,host:USE,cardType:DebitCard,product:Satin,Name:Raghav.S.Thomas,Region:UAE
```

Comment: Your first regexp has unmatched parenthesis and square bracket.

Comment: https://eval.in/189931

Comment: That's a lot of backslashes you have there. Most of them are redundant. For example, you do not need to escape `!"#%&',:;<=>_{}~` at all, and `*+?()|@^` do not need to be escaped inside a character class bracket `[ ... ]`.

Answer (score 3):

To capture between `Name:` and the first comma, use a [negated character class](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Negation):

```
/Name:([^,]+)/g
```

This says to match one or more characters following `Name:` which isn't a comma:

```
while (/Name:([^,]+)/g) {
    print $1, "\n";
}
```

This is more efficient than a non-greedy [quantifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quantifiers), e.g:

```
/Name:(.+?),/g
```

As it doesn't require [backtracking](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Backtracking).

Answer (score 0):

Reg-ex corrected:

```
my $line = "Name:Amanda_Marry_Rose,Region:US,host:USE,cardType:DebitCard,product:Satin,Name:Raghav.S.Thomas,Region:UAE,";

my @name = ($line =~ /Name\:([\w\s_.\/]+)\,/g);
    foreach my $name (@name) {
    print $name."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is comma separated data. How you should parse this depends a lot on your data. If it is full-fledged csv data, the most safe approach is to use a proper csv parser, such as [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV). If it is less strict data, you can get away with using the light-weight parser [`Text::ParseWords`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ParseWords), which also has the benefit of being a core module in Perl 5. If what you have here is rather basic, user entered fields, then I would recommend `split` -- simply because when you know the delimiter, it is easier and safer to define it, than everything else inside it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $line = "Name:Amanda_Marry_Rose,Region:US,host:USE,cardType:DebitCard,product:Satin,Name:Raghav.S.Thomas,Region:UAE,";

# Simple split
my @fields = split /,/, $line;
print Dumper for map /^Name:(.*)/, @fields;

use Text::ParseWords;
print Dumper map /^Name:(.*)/, quotewords(',', 0, $line);

use Text::CSV;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
        binary => 1,
    });
$csv->parse($line);
print Dumper map /^Name:(.*)/, $csv->fields;
```

Each of these options give the same output, save for the one that uses `Text::CSV`, which also issues an undefined warning, quite correctly, because your data has a trailing comma (meaning an empty field at the end).

Each of these has different strengths and weaknesses. `Text::CSV` can choke on data that does not conform with the CSV format, and `split` cannot handle embedded commas, such as `Name:"Doe, John",...`.

The regex we use to extract the names very simply just captures the entire rest of the lines that begin with `Name:`. This also allows you to perform sanity checks on the field names, for example issue a warning if you suddenly find a field called `Doe;Name:`

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to look for all sequences of non-comma characters after every instance of `Name:` in the string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = 'Name:Amanda_Marry_Rose,Region:US,host:USE,cardType:DebitCard,product:Satin,Name:Raghav.S.Thomas,Region:UAE,';

my @names = $line =~ /Name:([^,]+)/g;

print "$_\n" for @names;
```

**output**

```
Amanda_Marry_Rose
Raghav.S.Thomas
```

However, it may well be useful to parse the data into an array of hashes so that related fields are gathered together.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = 'Name:Amanda_Marry_Rose,Region:US,host:USE,cardType:DebitCard,product:Satin,Name:Raghav.S.Thomas,Region:UAE,';

my %info;
my @persons;
while ( $line =~ / ([a-z]+) : ([^:,]+) /gix ) {

   my ($key, $val) = (lc $1, $2);

   if ($info{$key}) {
     push @persons, { %info };
     %info = ();
   }

   $info{$key} = $val;
}
push @persons, { %info };

use Data::Dump;
dd \@persons;

print "\nNames:\n";
print "$_\n" for map $_->{name}, @persons;
```

**output**

```
[
  {
    cardtype => "DebitCard",
    host     => "USE",
    name     => "Amanda_Marry_Rose",
    product  => "Satin",
    region   => "US",
  },
  {
    name   => "Raghav.S.Thomas",
    region => "UAE",
  },
]

Names:
Amanda_Marry_Rose
Raghav.S.Thomas
```